# Cannot get value of form field of type 'file' in drupal form

Tags: forms, files

I have a form field  such as  ,

```
   $form['fileTransfer_settings']['file_path'] = array(
    '#type' => 'file',
    '#title' => t('Choose file'),
    '#size' => 22,
    '#description'   => t('path for the csv file'), 

  );
```

Now I am looking to save the path of the uploaded file in the submit handler ,

But when I look into the value of the form field in the submit handler I get null,

```
function transferfile_submit_handler($form, &$form_state) {

     dpm($form_state[values]); //other fields show value 
     dpm($form_state['values']['fileTransfer_settings']['file_path']); //null
 }
```

What  am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitted values are flattened unless the form element contains the `#tree` property.

So either use:

```
$form_state['values']['file_path'];
```

Or change the wrapper:

```
$form['fileTransfer_settings'] = array(
  '#tree' => TRUE,
  ...
);
```

And use your current submission code.